# ANGULAR:BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default

Tags: angular, google-auth-library

Installed google-auth-library, and when I imported JWT and used the object this error dump came:

```
./node_modules/gaxios/build/src/common.js:19:14-28 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in '/home/thor/Descargas/Trabajo/Armored/pruebaJWT/node_modules/gaxios/build/src'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
        - install 'url'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "url": false }

./node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:26:16-32 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/home/thor/Descargas/Trabajo/Armored/pruebaJWT/node_modules/gaxios/build/src'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
        - install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "https": false }

./node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:28:38-60 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'querystring' in '/home/thor/Descargas/Trabajo/Armored/pruebaJWT/node_modules/gaxios/build/src'
`
```

I can replicate this issue in a new project.
Also I'm aware of the solutions in other frameworks tweaking webpackconfig, but Angular does not have it.

I preciate any help

Tried: npm installing packages, downgrading webpack, attempted to create a customwebpackconfig.

Expecting: Run and compile